# Find different between 2 classes

Tags: xcode

After we put our game at the app store, we could see that there is some strange bug, so we remove it from the app store .

I have a version of the app in `Xcode` ,that i put in the App Store-that somehow is not working now . (does work on simulation)

I have also a previous version of the app that DO work .

I am trying to find the **differences** between them, and i can't.

Is there a way to compare two classes from other projects ?

Another thing, did i miss the Apple's first promotion of my app when i removed it now ? :(
Its so frustrating .

Comment: Are you using version control? If not, have you tried the `diff` command?

Comment: what version control (git, mercury,…) do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileMerge can be used to find the different between files or folder, it comes with Xcode. It is main used for text files, but it will tell you if other kinds of files are different also.